# Did the behavior of goto statements and their scope change, and when?

Tags: c#, .net, goto

I've decompiled a very old application using Telerik's JustDecompile.  I need to make a small change and rebuild the code.  But it fails to build in alot of places because of `goto` statements where the corresponding label is out of scope.

I can rewrite the logic flow to use flags / continue statements, but it's gonna be alot of work.  I'd like to know, did this behavior change at some point?  I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community - wondering if I can target an older C# version and/or .NET version where this code will compile as-is?

Here's an example of one of the many methods that hit compilation errors due to an out of scope label.  Towards the end there at the `goto label1;` it shows an error that no label1 exists in scope.

```
public static Dictionary<Guid, UpdateFuncs.UpdateEntry> GetUpdateList()
        {
            Dictionary<Guid, UpdateFuncs.UpdateEntry> guids;
            List<string> mirrors = UpdateFuncs.GetMirrors();
            Dictionary<Guid, UpdateFuncs.UpdateEntry> guids1 = new Dictionary<Guid, UpdateFuncs.UpdateEntry>();
            while (true)
            {
            Label1:
                UpdateFuncs.DoLog(string.Concat("Fetching updatelist, mirror ", mirrors[0]));
                try
                {
                    StreamReader file = UpdateFuncs.GetFile(mirrors[0]);
                    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDocument.Load(file);
                    XmlNode documentElement = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
                    if (new Version(documentElement.Attributes["Version"].Value) > Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Your version of this filter is out of date. You must install the latest version to get updates.");
                    }
                    foreach (XmlNode childNode in documentElement.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (!(childNode.Name != "update"))
                        {
                            UpdateFuncs.UpdateEntry updateEntry = new UpdateFuncs.UpdateEntry()
                            {
                                Name = childNode.Attributes["Name"].Value,
                                GUID = new Guid(childNode.Attributes["GUID"].Value),
                                SourceURL = childNode.Attributes["SourceURL"].Value,
                                Version = new Version(childNode.Attributes["Version"].Value),
                                Signature = childNode.Attributes["Signature"].Value,
                                IType = (UpdateFuncs.eItemType)int.Parse(childNode.Attributes["ItemType"].Value)
                            };
                            foreach (XmlNode xmlNodes in childNode.ChildNodes)
                            {
                                if (xmlNodes.Name == "prereq")
                                {
                                    UpdateFuncs.Prerequisite prerequisite = new UpdateFuncs.Prerequisite()
                                    {
                                        GUID = new Guid(xmlNodes.Attributes["GUID"].Value),
                                        IType = (UpdateFuncs.eItemType)int.Parse(xmlNodes.Attributes["ItemType"].Value),
                                        Version = new Version(xmlNodes.Attributes["Version"].Value)
                                    };
                                    updateEntry.Prerequisites.Add(prerequisite);
                                }
                            }
                            guids1.Add(updateEntry.GUID, updateEntry);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception1)
                {
                    Exception exception = exception1;
                    UpdateFuncs.DoLog(string.Concat("Error: ", exception.Message), Color.Red);
                    goto Label0;
                }
                guids = guids1;
                break;
            }
            return guids;
        Label0:
            mirrors.RemoveAt(0);
            if (mirrors.Count != 0)
            {
                goto Label1;
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateFuncs.DoLog("No more mirrors to try.");
                guids = new Dictionary<Guid, UpdateFuncs.UpdateEntry>();
                return guids;
            }
        }
```

Then there's a ton of methods where it gives a syntax error with labels.  Like this example below, where the `label0:` line towards the end gives the errors "CS1525    Invalid expression term '}'" and "CS1002    ; expected".

```
private void BeginUpdating()
        {
            this.PluginListbox.Visible = false;
            this.cmd1Install.Visible = false;
            this.cmd2Okay.Visible = false;
            this.lbl2InstDir.Visible = false;
            this.lbl2Message.Visible = false;
            this.btn2ChangeDir.Visible = false;
            Form1.AllocConsole();
            UpdateFuncs.LogMessage += new UpdateFuncs.delStringColor(this.UpdateFuncs_LogMessage);
            string text = this.lbl2InstDir.Text;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Plugins.Count; i++)
            {
                UpdateFuncs.UpdateEntry item = this.Plugins[i];
                UpdateFuncs.InstalledComponentInfo installedComponentInfo = this.InstalledInfo[i];
                if (!installedComponentInfo.Installed)
                {
                    string str = Path.Combine(text, this.GetDirectoryForComponentName(item.Name));
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Selected ", item.Name, " for install to ", str));
                    try
                    {
                        UpdateFuncs.DoUpdate(item, str);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Error: ", exception.Message));
                        goto Label0;
                    }
                }
                else if (installedComponentInfo.CurrentVersion.CompareTo(item.Version) < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Selected ", item.Name, " for update."));
                    try
                    {
                        UpdateFuncs.DoUpdate(item, installedComponentInfo.InstallDirectory);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Error: ", exception1.Message));
                        goto Label0;
                    }
                }
            Label0:
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Install complete. You may close this program.");
        }
```

Clearly since this is a compiled EXE that I've decompiled, this code worked at some point (although I guess maybe it coulda been VB and not C#?  I dunno?  I decompiled it to C#.  If possible I'd love to make this code work by changing project settings.  I know it's god awful code, but it's not mine and I really only need to comment out a few lines to make it work how I need.

Comment: Maybe this is more an issue with the Decompiler, as the decompiler is generating code. Which version are you using and how old is it?

Comment: I'd bet this application is from around 2004ish.  I'm starting to think it's actually VB6?  I dunno, I tried decompiling it to VB.NET instead of C#, still using JustDecompile, and now I don't get any errors about goto statements, but I get tons of errors about "Strings is not declared" on lines like 'If (chr1 = Strings.ChrW(95))'

Comment: Sry to answer earlier question about version, JustDecompile is the latest version, I just DLd it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was really just a VB.NET application, and my problem was decompiling it to C#.  Now that I've decompiled to VB.NET, I can build it but I've got a new set of problems to work through.  This question is kind of a moot point now though.  The goto label calls all work fine in VB.NET.

Comment: Try [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)

Comment: I've done some testing with various C# projects and decompiling them with JustDecompile, and it does put GOTO statements and labels in places where they never existed in the original C# code.  So it is the decompiler that is wrong here.  Thx for all the feedback.